# Multiple regression on unpaired data (A~B+C)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, permutation-test

I am not sure how to test one of my hypothesis from my data.
Basically, I have 3 behavioral measures A, B and C, and I want to test that A is a composite of B and C: A = B+C
However, for practical reasons, only one of this measure can be taken for each participant, i.e. I have the measure A for 30 participants, the measure B for another 30, and the measure C for another 30.
If my hypothesis was simply A=B I could do t tests or Wilcox, or if my data was paired I could use a regression, but I am not sure how to proceed.

In my opinion, a clean way would be to do some kind of double-layer permutation like this:

```
for in 1:10 000{

X = shuffle(B) + shuffle(C)

permtest(A, X)}
```

But I hope that they are existing tests or procedure that I could follow?

Comment: FloLe, since you say "I could do t test", I assume that your data would permit that if you only wanted to test A=B. Do you know how to test contrasts in an ANOVA? The t-test that I suggest in my answer is doing this " by hand ".

Answer (score 5):

#### Testing if "A=B+C" holds for the means

Since you do not have paired data, you can only test the hypothesis that the mean of A is equal to the sum of means of B and C, $\mu_A=\mu_B+\mu_C$, or equivalently, $\mu_A-\mu_B -\mu_C = 0$.

##### Your simulation based approach

You did not explain how you get to a final $p$-value in your simulations, where you permute $B$ and $C$, but I assume you would calculate the mean of the permtest p-values as final result, and this is fine. You can certainly cut down on the number of simulations.

##### If you can assume normality

If your data do not deviate much from a normal distribution, you can test this hypothesis with a $t$-test.

Here is the version to test if the [contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) A - B - C has mean zero. For such a $t$-test, compute the group averages $\bar{x}_A, \bar{x}_B, \bar{x}_C,$ and estimate the within-group variances as $s^2_A, s^2_B, s^2_C$.

Your test statistic,
$$
  t = \frac{\bar{x}_A - \bar{x}_B- \bar{x}_C}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_A}{n_A} + \frac{s^2_B}{n_B}+\frac{s^2_C}{n_C}}},
$$
here with $n_A=n_B=n_C=30$, follows approximately $t$-distributed with $df=n_A+n_B+n_C-3=87$ degrees of freedom.

The p-value for a *two-sided* test is  computed as
$$\text{pval} = 2(1-F_{t(87)}(|t|)),$$
where $F_{t(87)}$ is the cumulative distribution function of the t-distribution with 87 df. Make sure to take the absolute value.

Here is simple "home made" R code, assuming you have stored your data in three vectors `A`, `B`, `C`.

```r
nA <- length(A); nB <- length(B); nC <- length(C) 
n_all <- nA + nB + nC
abs_t <- abs(mean(A) - mean(B) - mean(C)) / 
          sqrt(var(A)/nA + var(B)/nB + var(C)/nC)
pval <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs_t, df = n_all - 3))
```

**Important:** when data are *paired*, you should neither use this test, nor the one suggested in the original post, see also @mkt's answer with simulated paired data. A test assuming independent data would have relatively low power then.

---

##### Update: you can have it much simpler

I realized that it makes no theoretical difference if you apply an ordinary two-sample $t$-test on group A and group (B+C) (still under normality assumption, R code):

```r
t.test(A, B+C)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, with this t test, if p<.05 it means A != B+C?

Comment: Yes, $p <. 05$ is evidence against mean(A) =mean(B+C), (last code: in R) . So not equal. If you have a one-sided hypothesis to start with, you can also test that.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have measurements of more than one measure on the same individual, I don't see how you can do a good evaluation of your idea (that A is exactly equal to B+C) with this data. Without some idea about what reality is, you are stuck with cruder comparisons of means and distributions. This may suffice to falsify your hypothesis (details at the end) but is insufficient to establish it with much confidence.

Here's a simulation of your idea, assuming that A = B+C.

```r
B <- rnorm(1000, 50, 10)
C <- rnorm(1000, 50, 10)
A <- B + C               # Here A = B + C by construction, with zero noise

#Creating an empty vector to save correlation values in
cor_list <- rep(NA, 1000)

# Repeating your suggested randomisation 10000 times and checking the correlation
for (i in 1:1000){
  D <- sample(B, 1000, replace = TRUE) + sample(C, 1000, replace = TRUE)
  cor_list[i] <- cor(A, D)
}

# Correlation is of course almost exactly zero
> mean(cor_list)
[1] -0.0008090246
```

Here's the relationship from one simulation:

[image: One simulation]

And here's a histogram of the correlation coefficients:

[image: Histogram of correlation coefficients]

Where does this leave you? You can compare the means and distributions of A and B+C (EDIT: as demonstrated nicely by Ute), as can be seen in the first plot. The fact that the means are both ~100 and the ranges are ~60-140 is informative. If instead (for example) the sum of the maximum value of B and the maximum value of C were still much less than even the minimum value of A, you would have strong evidence *against* your hypothesis. But without large assumptions, this procedure doesn't tell you whether A is equal to B+C.

Comment: Nice, and you are so fast, @mkt :-) But I see one problem: I am not sure if OP really wants to test A=B+C, or this is rather addressing the means of the measurements. In that case, you would have twice the variance in B+C as in A, and the permtest that OP suggested could be sensitive against that difference in variances, as it only checks if two distributions are identical (with emphasis on equality of means, though). Apart from that, it is nice to have two complementary solutions, and I would not need to go further with mine :-)

Comment: @Ute Thanks, and I like your approach but OP seemed quite explicit about their goal: "*I want to test that A is a composite of B and C: A = B+C*"

Comment: Ah, you are right! I stumbled upon " composite" but then reinterpreted the goal. Can you point this out in your answer (just in case someone drops by with non normal data and right away uses OP/your version) ? I am not sure what would happen when B and C are somewhat complicatedly dependent on each other, but there is nothing to do about this anyway

Comment: @Ute Sure, done.

Comment: +1 to your answer, because it gives incentive to simulate and explore - this is always a good idea imho! However, I do not think that op's idea is to blame for suboptimal power, it is the sampling design, and any test has to follow that design. It is possible that measurements cannot be done concurrently, just technically, so maybe they have no chance to improve.

Comment: @Ute Yes, I said in my first sentence that it is the design that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, indeed there isn't really a way to get more than one measure per individual, but I am satisfied with testing the means and distributions as you suggested!